# Font scaling in mixed-font writing

Tags: fonts, scaling

How can I scale up/down the size of a font so that it looks coherent when mixed with other fonts on the same line?

As a concrete example, how can the first 'a' in the following snippet be scaled down to the size of the second and third?

[image: a-character-in-different-sizes]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\pagmsl{\usefont{\encodingdefault}{pag}{m}{sl}}
\newcommand\pbklit{\usefont{\encodingdefault}{pbk}{l}{it}}
\newcommand\bchmit{\usefont{\encodingdefault}{bch}{m}{it}}

\begin{document}

\pagmsl a
\pbklit a
\bchmit  a

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are able to use the `fontspec` package, you might want to try out the `[Scale=MatchLowercase]` option, which automatically scales the fonts to the same x-height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forcing a bit the font selection scheme, you can define a command `\definesamplefont` that defines a whole new font family based on the main font x-height. You can typeset paragraphs with the newly defined font switches.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \compute \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definesamplefont}[4]{%
  \sbox0{\normalfont a}%
  \sbox2{\normalfont\usefont{\encodingdefault}{#2}{#3}{#4}a%
         \xdef\@temp{\fontname\font\space}}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\DeclareFontFamily{\encodingdefault}{#1}{}
    \noexpand\DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{#1}{X}{X}
     { <-> [\compute{\strip@pt\ht0/\strip@pt\ht2}] \expandafter\xget@name\@temp\@nil }{}
  }\x
 \@namedef{#1}{\usefont{\encodingdefault}{#1}{X}{X}}
}
\def\xget@name#1 #2\@nil{#1}
\makeatother
\definesamplefont{pagmsl}{pag}{m}{sl}
\definesamplefont{pbklit}{pbk}{l}{it}
\definesamplefont{bchmit}{bch}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

\pagmsl a
\pbklit a
\bchmit a

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way to get the required ratio is to use the package `fp`. Here's the complete example for this case:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{fp}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definesamplefont}[4]{%
  \sbox0{\normalfont a}%
  \sbox2{\normalfont\usefont{\encodingdefault}{#2}{#3}{#4}a%
         \xdef\@temp{\fontname\font\space}}%
  \FPdiv\computed@ratio{\number\ht0}{\number\ht2}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\DeclareFontFamily{\encodingdefault}{#1}{}
    \noexpand\DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{#1}{X}{X}
     { <-> [\computed@ratio] \expandafter\xget@name\@temp\@nil }{}
  }\x
 \@namedef{#1}{\usefont{\encodingdefault}{#1}{X}{X}}
}
\def\xget@name#1 #2\@nil{#1}
\makeatother
\definesamplefont{pagmsl}{pag}{m}{sl}
\definesamplefont{pbklit}{pbk}{l}{it}
\definesamplefont{bchmit}{bch}{m}{it}

\begin{document}
a
\pagmsl a
\pbklit a
\bchmit a

\end{document}
```

---

A full expl3 implementation of the same code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definesamplefont}{mmmm}
 {
  \calaf_define_sample_font:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\box_new:N \l__calaf_normal_ht_box
\hbox_set:Nn \l__calaf_normal_ht_box {\normalfont a}
\box_new:N \l__calaf_new_ht_box
\tl_new:N \g__calaf_fontname_tl
\seq_new:N \l__calaf_fontname_seq
\fp_new:N \l__calaf_ratio_fp

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \calaf_define_sample_font:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__calaf_new_ht_box
   {
    \normalfont\usefont{\encodingdefault}{#2}{#3}{#4} a
    \seq_set_split:Nnx \l__calaf_fontname_seq { ~ } { \fontname\font \c_space_tl }
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__calaf_fontname_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_gset_eq:NN \g__calaf_fontname_tl \l_tmpa_tl
   }
  \fp_set:Nn \l__calaf_ratio_fp
   {
    \dim_to_fp:n { \box_ht:N \l__calaf_normal_ht_box}
    /
    \dim_to_fp:n {\box_ht:N \l__calaf_new_ht_box }
   }
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:N \DeclareFontFamily {\encodingdefault} {#1} {}
    \exp_not:N \DeclareFontShape  {\encodingdefault} {#1} {X} {X}
     { <-> [ \fp_use:N \l__calaf_ratio_fp ] \g__calaf_fontname_tl } {}
   }
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } {  \usefont{\encodingdefault}{#1}{X}{X} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\definesamplefont{pagmsl}{pag}{m}{sl}
\definesamplefont{pbklit}{pbk}{l}{it}
\definesamplefont{bchmit}{bch}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

\pagmsl a
\pbklit a
\bchmit a

\end{document}
```

Comment: On my side, pdflatex bails out at '\compute'.

Comment: @Calaf You need to update your TeX distribution, then.

Comment: I'm running MacTeX 2012. I guess even the TeX crowd has become so keen on being bleeding edge that not updating four months after the release of 2013 makes my installation obsolete.

Comment: @Calaf There should be other ways to define `\compute`; I'll try with other packages. But an upgrade to MacTeX 2013 is recommended anyway.

Comment: Confirmed: Upgrading to 2013 did indeed solve the issue.

Comment: @Calaf So you can use the final version. ;-) The main problem is that expl3 is work in progress and, in particular, fixed point computations have been revamped in the meantime.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of vertical height, you can store some fixed height in a length and scale elements to that height elsewhere in your document.

Below I've used `\resizebox{!}{\fixedheight}{<stuff>}` to resize `<stuff>` to the height of `\fixedheight` (whatever that may be; `a` in Computer Modern in my case below):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\pagmsl{\usefont{\encodingdefault}{pag}{m}{sl}}
\newcommand\pbklit{\usefont{\encodingdefault}{pbk}{l}{it}}
\newcommand\bchmit{\usefont{\encodingdefault}{bch}{m}{it}}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\fixedheight}\settoheight{\fixedheight}{a}

\fbox{%
  a
  {\pagmsl a}
  {\pbklit a}
  {\bchmit a}%
}

\fbox{%
  a
  \resizebox{!}{\fixedheight}{\pagmsl a}
  \resizebox{!}{\fixedheight}{\pbklit a}
  \resizebox{!}{\fixedheight}{\bchmit a}%
}
\end{document}
```

Of course the caveat here is that you won't enjoy line-breaking with this approach. However, your example listed only characters. Moreover, you will lose certain dimensions with the scaling.

[`scalerel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/scalerel) provides similar functionality.